# Browserify version of Nodejs form-data throws error when appending buffers and streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, form-data

I am trying to create a `FormData` object in my browserified code. However, it is not working the same way it did in NodeJS. Here is my code:

```js
let body = {
  type: "Introductory",
  answeringRule: { id: "36" },
};

const NodeFormData = require("form-data");
formData = new NodeFormData();

formData.append("json", new Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(body)), {
  filename: "request.json",
  contentType: "application/json",
});

formData.append("binary", audioStream, {
  filename: "audioStream.mp3",
  contentType: "audio/mpeg",
});
```

In NodeJS this code worked perfectly, appending both the buffer section and the `ReadableStream` section to the `FormData`. When I run this in the browserify version, it throws the error:

> "Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'."

I am aware that JavaScript has a native `FormData` constructor as well and I've tried it with both the native version ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData)) and the Browserify NodeJS version and both throw the same error. For my use case I cannot attach these pieces of data as actual Blobs. If I did, then they wouldn't be readable for the next step in the process.

How can I resolve this?

Why doesn't the Browserify version of form-data work the same as the NodeJS version?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

It turns out that the `FormData` type in the [Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) (as seen in `lib.dom.d.ts`) is different to that in Node (the [`form-data`](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/blob/master/index.d.ts) library) as it only allows strings and Blobs in the `append` method.

**Web API implementation**

```js
interface FormData {
    append(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
    delete(name: string): void;
    get(name: string): FormDataEntryValue | null;
    getAll(name: string): FormDataEntryValue[];
    has(name: string): boolean;
    set(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: FormDataEntryValue, key: string, parent: FormData) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
}
```

**Node/`form-data`:**

```js
declare class FormData extends stream.Readable {
  constructor(options?: Options);
  append(key: string, value: any, options?: FormData.AppendOptions | string): void;
  getHeaders(userHeaders?: FormData.Headers): FormData.Headers;
  submit(
    params: string | FormData.SubmitOptions,
    callback?: (error: Error | null, response: http.IncomingMessage) => void
  ): http.ClientRequest;
  getBuffer(): Buffer;
  setBoundary(boundary: string): void;
  getBoundary(): string;
  getLength(callback: (err: Error | null, length: number) => void): void;
  getLengthSync(): number;
  hasKnownLength(): boolean;
}
```

In my case, I had to refactor my code to turn my buffer into a Blob for it to work.

Node implementation:

```js
formData.append('file', fileResponseBuffer, { filename, contentType });
```

Browserify implementation:

```js
formData.append('file', new Blob([await fileResponse.arrayBuffer()]), filename);
```

The different implementation and signatures also requires you to change how you pass it to, for example, the `fetch` API.

Node:

```js
const response = await fetch('/api/filemanager/upload', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData.getBuffer(),
  headers: formData.getHeaders()
});
```

Browserify:

```js
const response = await fetch('/api/filemanager/upload', {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData
});
```

Hope this helps, it was a bit of a nightmare to figure out.